# Can a jar compiled with a higher targetSdkVersion be used in an app that has a lower targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Is the following possible in Android?
Say I have a project 'ProjA' compiled with targetSdkVersion, say 18, which generates projA.jar
I have another project 'ProjB' having targetSdkVersion 17.
Is it possible to use projA.jar within 'ProjB' without encountering any issues, due to the differences in their targetSdkVersion?

Comment: jar is jar ... obviously, if ProjA is not using newer API there should be no problem ... different story is with aar

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Android you don't compile jar files, you compile .APK.
As the answer to your question, yes, you must compile with the highest targetSdkVersion as the field that limits the API level for your application is the minimumSdkVersion. In the examples you provide with ProjA and ProjB, as far as i know, there should be no problem as long as there aren't any inconsistencies with minimumSdkVersion